# Provability vs. implication?

Tags: logic, provability

For any logic we have an `is provable from` relation denoted by $S \vdash \phi$ where $S$ is a (for the sake of the argument lets say) finite set of sentences and $\phi$ is a sentence.

Is the following “meta-theorem” valid?

$S\vdash \phi\quad \text{ iff } \quad \emptyset \vdash \left(\bigwedge S \implies \phi\right)$ where $\bigwedge S$ is the conjunction of all sentences in $S$.

(Assume that the logic in question has the deductive system capable of handling the conjunction and the implication in the usual way.)

Comment: One usually uses $\to$ in that place instead of $\implies$.

Comment: That is more or less called the deduction theorem.  Most logics either have that an axiom or are specifically designed to make that statement true.

Comment: Note that it only meaningful when $S$ is finite, so it's not just "for the sake of the argument". =)

Comment: Not necessarily; see Raul Hakli & Sara Negri, [Does the deduction theorem fail for modal logic ?](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.669.2062&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (2012)

Answer (score 0):

I think so.

Given $S \vdash \phi$, we prove $\bigwedge S \Rightarrow \phi$ by using a law of implication introduction / conditional proof by assuming $\bigwedge S$, deriving the sentences in $S$, then using $S \vdash \phi$ to get $\phi$, and finally applying the law of implication introduction (with the details depending on the particular logical system).

Conversely, given $\emptyset \vdash (\bigwedge S \Rightarrow \phi)$, we assume $S$, conjoin the sentences to derive $\bigwedge S$, also derive $\bigwedge S \Rightarrow \phi$ (for free), and then use modus ponens to derive $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $S \vdash \phi$.

Now, I claim that $\varnothing \vdash \bigwedge S \to \phi$, because I can create the following proof:

```
    1.      ⋀S   [assumption]
    2-n.    (decomposes the wedge)
    n+1-??. adjoin the proof given
    ??.     ϕ
??+1. ⋀S→ϕ [→intro]
```

---

Assume $\varnothing \vdash \bigwedge S \to \phi$.

Now, I claim that $S \vdash \phi$, because I can create the following proof:

```
1-n.      (restatement of the premises)
n+1-2n-1. (conjunction of the restatements into ⋀S)
2n.       ⋀S
2n+1-???. (copy the proof of ⋀S→ϕ)
???.      ⋀S→ϕ
???+1.    ϕ   [modus ponens (aka →elim)]
```

Comment: You may want to edit to clarify what "`n+1-2n-1`" means. Is it just "−2n"? =)

Answer (score 0):

This is clear from the Soundness and Completeness theorems. (Since it's more or less obvious that $S\models \phi$ if and only if $\models \bigwedge S\implies \phi$.)

Comment: But your proof requires the theory to be that of a first-order.

Comment: @KennyLau Well, yes - I assumed that was what we were talking about.